# Как правильно переместить компонент внутри шаблона сайта на Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с такой проблемой.

Есть страница страница каталога на сайте (Битрикс) собирается из папки catalog.section template.php

В верхней части этой страницы располагается списком перечисление других рубрик этого раздела каталога. Собирается  из другой папки catalog.section.list файл template.php

Задача перенести этот список рубрик вниз страницы. Каким образом сделать правильно это в битриксе?

Пробовала метод "в лоб" - вырезать часть этого кода и вставить в нужное место страницы - никаких реакций. Документация битрикса мне тоже, увы не помогает.

Comment: как вариант гляньте на реализацию через https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/showviewcontent.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если используется комплексный компонент каталог `bitrix:catalog`, то в шаблоне `/bitrix/templates/{название шаблона сайта}/bitrix/catalog/{название шаблона компонента}/section.php` перенести вызов

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent( 
    "bitrix:catalog.section.list",
...
?>
```

ниже в нужное место.

А если без комплексного,то перенести вызов того же компонента что указан выше в файле в файловой системе (к примеру если страница `http://site/catalog/` , то в файле `/catalog/index.php`)

Comment: дело в том, что файл catalog.section.list содержит внутри несколько прописанных компонентов, а нужен только один, который показывает количество элементов в разделе. как именно его перенести вниз?

Comment: образовались новые нейронные связи и до меня только что дошло ) Спасибо большое )

Comment: Но никак не могу понять как именно компонент, который подсчитывает количество объектов в других категориях и выводит его, только его перенести вниз. Если просто изменить место подключения, то он все, что содержит каталог секш лист переносит. Этого и не надо